# How to handle notification popup in child window or new tab using selenium?

Tags: notifications, popupwindow, chrome-options

In salesforce application, i see notification popup displaying which i could able handle using chrome options but when i click some links new child window or new tab opens with the notification popup. How can we disable those in middle of execution?
Example: Parent Window A
Child window B
When we click some thing on window A, Window B opens with notification popup and authentication window popups.

I could able to handle all notification on parent window using chrome options [—-disable notification] but not on child window.